# Importing GeoPandas in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, python, import, geopandas, anaconda

Here is the situation: I've installed QGIS 3.10 with the downloadable `.exe` file and accepting all as predefined. The Python version used with it is 3.7.0 like here:

```py
import sys
sys.version
'3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

The thing now is that I'm working on a script that need GeoPandas and I'm not able to install or import it:

```py
import geopandas
```

The above command prompts this `ModuleNotFoundError` error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>     exec(code, self.locals)
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
>     mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
> ```

I tried to install Anaconda and within it I'm able to install pip and GeoPandas without any issues but it comes with Python 3.7.4. I have no deep understanding about how several Python versions work together within the same PC.

So, my issue here is easy: I need to be able to import GeoPandas in the Python console regarding that I use QGIS 3.10 and it works with Python 3.7.0. I use Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried installing QGIS in a conda environment? Here is a great tutorial on the subject: https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2019/05/29/using-qgis-from-conda/

Comment: I'm aware of it, thanks. The goal is to create a python script that works in several machines and with users that doesn't have any knowledge about python. I hope there is a simple solution on this just to import and execute geopandas tools from the python console in QGIS 3.10

Answer (score 3):

In order to install the module with the right Python, it is better to use `python -m pip install geopandas` instead of `pip install geopandas`. You can follow the following steps:

1. Find python.exe which is in your QGIS folder. (Example: `C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37`)
2. Opens a command prompt
3. Type the following command: `cd C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37 & python -m pip install geopandas`

Replace the `OSGEO` path with your QGIS path.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get the following error when installing geopandas: "Collection fiona [...] ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: [...] Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.

Comment: The installation of the geopandas module requires numerous dependencies on other modules and frequently returns numerous error messages. A similar question was asked in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda

Comment: I though this would be much easier, like a pair of code lines or something... When I try that fiona manual instalation a new problem comes to light: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. This just never ends...

Answer (score 3):

Try the following procedure. This worked for me with QGIS 3.10.1 and Windows 10. The only difference is that I have an OSGeo4W install, so hopefully it will work for you with a standalone install.

Firstly, go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona and download the file:

Fiona‑1.8.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl

Next create a batch file with the following contents (this should work for your standalone installation):

```
@echo off
rem Root OSGEO4W home dir to the same directory this script exists in
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\python-qgis.bat"

rem List available o4w programs
rem but only if osgeo4w called without parameters
@echo on
@if [%1]==[] (echo run o-help for a list of available commands & cmd.exe /k) else (cmd /c "%*")
```

For an OSGeo4W64 installation, the batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
rem Root OSGEO4W home dir to the same directory this script exists in
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\python-qgis.bat"

rem List available o4w programs
rem but only if osgeo4w called without parameters
@echo on
@if [%1]==[] (echo run o-help for a list of available commands & cmd.exe /k) else (cmd /c "%*")
```

Just make sure that `OSGEO4W_ROOT` is set to the directory which contains your installation folders (apps, bin etc). Save this with a .bat extension- preferably in the same OSGEO4W_ROOT directory.

Now, when you double click this batch file it should open you up to a Python prompt in a command window. Type `quit()` and hit enter. This should return you to a command prompt with the qgis python environment correctly set.

The following steps are more or less based on Underdark (Anita Graser)'s instructions [here](https://anitagraser.com/2019/02/02/movement-data-in-gis-20-trajectools-v1-released/).

Type `pip install geopandas` and hit enter. The installation will error at Fiona.

Now type 'pip install C:\Full\Path\To\Fiona‑1.8.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl' and hit enter. **Note** - you need to type the full path to the location where you saved the wheel (.whl) file including the file name. This should successfully install Fiona.

Now type `pip install geopandas` again and hit enter. If all goes well, this will successfully install geopandas.

Now you can just type `exit()` and hit enter to exit the command window. Job done!

Comment: For a stand alone QGIS I get this error, any idea ? ```ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\bin\python3.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\brichard\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-335sm5vb\\gdal_a7341d33252a43858398c96c78e3ffa9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\brichard\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-335sm5vb\\gdal_a7341d33252a43858398c96c78e3ffa9\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file ...```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question in my own quest to install geopandas for qgis and I figured this might be useful for future reference: I am using an osgeo4w installation of qgis 3.16 (it may be available in previous versions but I haven't  checked) and geopandas 0.7.0 is now available through the OSGeo4w setup. This probably won't be the solution for everyone but I figured I would add it as an option, especially since using wheels isn't recommended for use with an OSGeo4w installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the SSL-Error, go to OSGeo-Shell, type in `py3_env` and check whether `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib` is in your path. If not then use the set command as in the result of `py3_env` to add it. For me it wouldn't work otherwise.