# GDAL Fails Importation of GeoPandas to QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, geopandas

I am trying to install GeoPandas on QGIS.
I have first checked these pages :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bm3qyh1fO-M
- https://anitagraser.com/2019/02/02/movement-data-in-gis-20-trajectools-v1-released/
- [How to import GeoPandas in QGIS 3.10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346859/how-to-import-geopandas-in-qgis-3-10)

I am on Windows and have another installation of Python (out of QGIS) with an environnement containing GeoPandas.
But I think I have some trouble with gdal, I do not where I should look closer.

The farthest I get led me to this error :

```
pip install C:\Users\brichard\Desktop\Temporaire\QGIS_GeoPandas\Fiona-1.8.18-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\brichard\desktop\temporaire\qgis_geopandas\fiona-1.8.18-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: click-plugins>=1.0 in c:\users\brichard\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.18) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: munch in c:\users\brichard\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.18) (2.5.0)
Collecting gdal~=3.2.1
  Using cached GDAL-3.2.2.tar.gz (601 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.18) (2020.4.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7 in c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.18) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8,>=4.0 in c:\users\brichard\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.18) (7.1.2)
Collecting attrs>=17
  Using cached attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cligj>=0.5 in c:\users\brichard\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.18) (0.7.1)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for gdal, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: gdal, attrs, Fiona
  Attempting uninstall: gdal
    Found existing installation: GDAL 3.1.4
    Uninstalling GDAL-3.1.4:
      Successfully uninstalled GDAL-3.1.4
    Running setup.py install for gdal ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\bin\python3.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\brichard\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gfmvfgic\\gdal_3b3775ef6fbb4f35bcaf8cc2128b32e7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\brichard\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gfmvfgic\\gdal_3b3775ef6fbb4f35bcaf8cc2128b32e7\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\brichard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zbjwj0yr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\Include\gdal'
         cwd: C:\Users\brichard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gfmvfgic\gdal_3b3775ef6fbb4f35bcaf8cc2128b32e7\
    Complete output (52 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gnm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\epsg_tr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\esri2wkt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gcps2vec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gcps2wld.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal2xyz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdalchksum.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdalcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdalident.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdalimport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdalmove.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal_auth.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal_calc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal_edit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal_fillnodata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal_merge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal_pansharpen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal_polygonize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal_proximity.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal_retile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\gdal_sieve.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\mkgraticule.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\ogrmerge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\pct2rgb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\rgb2pct.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    copying osgeo\utils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils
    Fixing build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdal_array.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gnm.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\ogr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\__init__.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\epsg_tr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\esri2wkt.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gcps2vec.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gcps2wld.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal2xyz.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdalchksum.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdalcompare.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdalident.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdalimport.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdalmove.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_auth.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_calc.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_edit.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_fillnodata.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_merge.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_pansharpen.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_polygonize.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_proximity.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_retile.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_sieve.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\mkgraticule.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\ogrmerge.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\pct2rgb.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\rgb2pct.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\__init__.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    Fixing build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdal_array.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gnm.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\ogr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\__init__.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\epsg_tr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\esri2wkt.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gcps2vec.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gcps2wld.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal2xyz.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdalchksum.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdalcompare.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdalident.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdalimport.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdalmove.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_auth.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_calc.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_edit.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_fillnodata.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_merge.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_pansharpen.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_polygonize.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_proximity.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_retile.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\gdal_sieve.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\mkgraticule.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\ogrmerge.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\pct2rgb.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\rgb2pct.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\utils\__init__.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    building 'osgeo._gdalconst' extension
    building 'osgeo._osr' extension
    building 'osgeo._ogr' extension
    building 'osgeo._gnm' extension
    building 'osgeo._gdal_array' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of GDAL
  Moving to c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\gdal-3.1.4-py3.7.egg-info
   from c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\~dal-3.1.4-py3.7.egg-info
  Moving to c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\gdal.py
   from C:\Users\brichard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-uelukzgs\gdal.py
  Moving to c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\gdalconst.py
   from C:\Users\brichard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-uelukzgs\gdalconst.py
  Moving to c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\gdalnumeric.py
   from C:\Users\brichard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-uelukzgs\gdalnumeric.py
  Moving to c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\ogr.py
   from C:\Users\brichard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-uelukzgs\ogr.py
  Moving to c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\osgeo
   from c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\~sgeo
  Moving to c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\osr.py
   from C:\Users\brichard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-uelukzgs\osr.py
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\bin\python3.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\brichard\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gfmvfgic\\gdal_3b3775ef6fbb4f35bcaf8cc2128b32e7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\brichard\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gfmvfgic\\gdal_3b3775ef6fbb4f35bcaf8cc2128b32e7\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\brichard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zbjwj0yr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\Include\gdal' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here :
https://www.programmersought.com/article/30186436754/

I had to install a newer version of gdal.

1. Download from official website, download address:[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)
2. `pip install GDAL-2.2.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
3. `pip install Fiona-1.8.19-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`
4. `pip install geopandas`